# Modifying predefined 'params' var in Sinatra renders it nil

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Consider the simple following code:

```
post '/xxx' do
    puts params
end
```

this works fine. Now consider the following modification

```
post '/xxx' do
    params = params
    puts params
end
```

Now params is nil!! I am new to Ruby, and have no idea why this behaviour is happening. Obviously I do not want to execute the useless `params = params` expression, but I was trying to to something a little more complicated involving modifying `params` and found that it always becomes `nil`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first version, you're calling a method called `params` and passing its return value to `puts`.

In the second version, you're creating a local variable called `params` (which hides the method with the same name) and assigning it to itself.

Consider the following example:

```
def foo
  1
end

p foo # outputs `1`

foo = foo

p foo # outputs `nil`
```

It might not be obvious that this is happening, because in Ruby accessing a local variable and calling a method on `self` look exactly the same.

Comment: Well that was very silly of me. I know about this behaviour in other languages and it should have hit me.

Comment: Don't be too hard on yourself. The lack of required parenthese on method calls is probably my least favourite thing about Ruby. It's easy to understand the intention of well written Ruby code, but understanding how it's implemented takes more effort than languages like Python because of this kind of ambiguity.